# Using triangle Inequality to solve inequality.

Tags: inequality

Question from a textbook.

Show that for non negative $x,y,z$ that 
$$ (x+y+z) \sqrt{2}  \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{ y^2 + z^2} + \sqrt{x^2 +z^2}  $$

and that for $ 0< x \leq y \leq z$,

$$ \sqrt{y^2 +z^2} \leq x\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{(y-x)^2 +(z-x)^2} $$

,which the hint was to utilize the triangle inequality to "an appropriate sum". How does these approaches work? Is there a way to "know" beforehand what these sums are?

Comment: I solved also your second problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $a)$ use $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}} \ge \dfrac{a+b}{2}$ , add them up ( $3$ of them ). And 
$b)$ the triangle inequality applies to $3$ vertices $A(y,z)$ , $B(x,x)$ , and $O(0,0)$ which reads $OA \le OB + AB$ which is true.

OK. Again for $a)$, the $\triangle$ - inequality you want will be seen through the following construction: Assume $a \le b$, let: $O(0,0), C(a,b), D(b,a), M(a+b,a+b)$. Then the quadrilateral $OCMD$ is a parallelogram and the inequality above translates to: $OC + OD = OC + CM \ge OM = OB + BM = OB + OA $ which is true. Then repeat this for each pair $(x,y), (y,z)$ , and $(x,z)$ and add them up also.

Comment: And this works just because all $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negative.

Comment: What about using the triangle inequality for $a)$?

Comment: @299792458: See my edit post .

Answer (score 0):

1. $(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{ y^2 + z^2} + \sqrt{x^2 +z^2} )^2= 2(x^2 + y^2+ z^2) + \;\;non-negative\;\; terms\geq 2(x^2 + y^2+ z^2)$

which yields the first inequality.

2. $(y-x)^2 + (z-x)^2=y^2+z^2+2x^2-2x(y+z)\geq y^2+z^2+2x^2-2\sqrt{2}x(\sqrt{y^2+z^2})=(\sqrt{y^2+z^2}-\sqrt{2}x)^2$

yields the second inequality.